# boolean result doesn't change in constructor

Tags: java, android, timer, boolean

I have a method that changes the value of a boolean variable if something happened..

```
for (Message msg : msgs) {
        if (!msgs_array.contains(msg)) {
            Log.d("Chat", "Message : " + msg.getTitle() + ": "
                    + msg.getMessage());
                    msgs_array.add(msg);
            newMsg = true;
            Log.d("Chat", "New Message ? " + newMsg);
        }
    }
```

And I have a timer in my constructor :

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("Chat", "Has New Msg ? " + newMsg);
                }
            });

        }
    }, 2000, 2000);
```

When the condition is made I get in the log cat : New Message ? true
but my timer still logs it as false..

So.. Any Idea ? :S

Comment: where do you declare newMsg ? Is Timer really created in the constructor ? or in the onCreate ?

Comment: Its a field in my class ..

Comment: Please add the (relevant) code that contains the two listings above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this doesn answer your question but i suggest you use `handler` and not `timertask`.
Read about it here  http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/

you can exactly replicate this using handler.. :-/

Comment: No.. The boolean is never used in somewhere else i mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

i think `string comparing` is working in your code, replace the variables with `equals()`.

just try this, hope it helps

```
for (Message msg : msgs) {
        if (!msg.equals(msgs_array)) {
            Log.d("Chat", "Message : " + msg.getTitle() + ": "
                    + msg.getMessage());
                    msgs_array.add(msg);
            newMsg = true;
            Log.d("Chat", "New Message ? " + newMsg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but that won't work cuz msgs_array is an array of Message class and I think that condition is right cuz the Log works fine

Comment: did u tried like this? `if (!msgs_array.equals(msg))`